# How to convert multiple json files to cvs files

Tags: python

Hello I have multiple json files in a path and I want to convert all of them to csv files separately. Here is what I have tried so far which just convert one json file to a csv file.

```
with open('/Users/hh/MyDataSet/traceJSON-663-661-A0-25449-7.json') as f:
  for line in f:
     data.append(json.loads(line))

csv_file=open('/Users/hh/MyDataSet/GTruth/traceJSON-663-661-A0-25449-7.csv','w')

write=csv.writer(csv_file)
# write.writerow(["row number","type","rcvTime","pos_x","pos_y","pos_z","spd_x","spd_y","spd_z","acl_x","acl_y","acl_z"
#                 ,"hed_x","hed_y","hed_z"])
write.writerow(["row number","type","rcvTime","sender","pos_x","pos_y","pos_z","spd_x","spd_y","spd_z","acl_x","acl_y","acl_z"
                ,"hed_x","hed_y","hed_z"])
for elem in range(len(data)):    
   if data[elem]['type']==2:
     write.writerow([elem,data[elem]['type'],round(data[elem]['rcvTime'],2),'663',round(data[elem]['pos'][0],2),round(data[elem]['pos'][1],2)
                   ,round(data[elem]['pos'][2],2),round(data[elem]['spd'][0],2),round(data[elem]['spd'][1],2),round(data[elem]['spd'][2],2),
                   round(data[elem]['acl'][0],2),round(data[elem]['acl'][1],2),round(data[elem]['acl'][2],2),round(data[elem]['hed'][0],2),
                  round(data[elem]['hed'][1],2),round(data[elem]['hed'][2],2)])
   elif data[elem]['type']==3:
     write.writerow([elem,data[elem]['type'],round(data[elem]['rcvTime'],2),round(data[elem]['sender'],2),round(data[elem]['pos'][0],2),round(data[elem]['pos'][1],2)
                   ,round(data[elem]['pos'][2],2),round(data[elem]['spd'][0],2),round(data[elem]['spd'][1],2),round(data[elem]['spd'][2],2),
                   round(data[elem]['acl'][0],2),round(data[elem]['acl'][1],2),round(data[elem]['acl'][2],2),round(data[elem]['hed'][0],2),
                  round(data[elem]['hed'][1],2),round(data[elem]['hed'][2],2)])
# json_file.close()
print('done!')
csv_file.close()
```

I appreciate if anyone can help me how can I do it. Also in each json file name "traceJSON-663-661-A0-25449-7", the first number like in the above code (663) should be written in csv file like the following code,if the type is 2:

```
write.writerow([elem,data[elem]['type'],round(data[elem]['rcvTime'],2),'663',....
```

My json file names are like traceJSON-51-49-A16-25217-7, traceJSON-57-55-A0-25223-7, ....

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `pandas` for this:

```
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd
import os

filepaths = glob('/Users/hh/MyDataSet/*.json') # get list of json files in folder

for f in filepaths:
    filename = os.path.basename(f).rsplit('.', 1)[0] # extract filename without extension
    nr = int(filename.split('-')[1]) # extract the number from the filename - assuming that all filenames are formatted similarly, use regex otherwise
    df = pd.read_json(f) # read the json file as a pandas dataframe, assuming the json file isn't nested
    df['type'] = df['type'].replace(2, nr) # replace 2 in 'type' column with the number in the filename
    df.to_csv(f'{filename}.csv') # save as csv
```

If you want to round columns, you can also do this with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually I want to say if the type=2 then the sender for that line should be the first number in the filename.

Comment: I men I want the format of csv file to be exactly what I wrote.

Comment: If you want to replace the value in sender if type is 2, you can do so with: `df.loc[df['type'] == 2, "sender"] = nr`

Answer (score 1):

```py
import csv
import glob
import json
import os.path

for src_path in glob.glob('/Users/hh/MyDataSet/*.json'):
    src_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(src_path))[0]

    data = []
    with open(src_path) as f:
      for line in f:
         data.append(json.loads(line))

    dest_path = '/Users/hh/MyDataSet/GTruth/' + src_name + '.csv'
    csv_file=open(dest_path,'w')

    write=csv.writer(csv_file)
    write.writerow(["row number","type","rcvTime","sender","pos_x","pos_y","pos_z","spd_x","spd_y","spd_z","acl_x","acl_y","acl_z"
                ,"hed_x","hed_y","hed_z"])
    for elem in range(len(data)):    
       if data[elem]['type']==2:
         sender = src_name.split('-')[1]
         write.writerow([elem,data[elem]['type'],round(data[elem]['rcvTime'],2),sender,round(data[elem]['pos'][0],2),round(data[elem]['pos'][1],2)
                   ,round(data[elem]['pos'][2],2),round(data[elem]['spd'][0],2),round(data[elem]['spd'][1],2),round(data[elem]['spd'][2],2),
                   round(data[elem]['acl'][0],2),round(data[elem]['acl'][1],2),round(data[elem]['acl'][2],2),round(data[elem]['hed'][0],2),
                  round(data[elem]['hed'][1],2),round(data[elem]['hed'][2],2)])
       elif data[elem]['type']==3:
         write.writerow([elem,data[elem]['type'],round(data[elem]['rcvTime'],2),round(data[elem]['sender'],2),round(data[elem]['pos'][0],2),round(data[elem]['pos'][1],2)
                   ,round(data[elem]['pos'][2],2),round(data[elem]['spd'][0],2),round(data[elem]['spd'][1],2),round(data[elem]['spd'][2],2),
                   round(data[elem]['acl'][0],2),round(data[elem]['acl'][1],2),round(data[elem]['acl'][2],2),round(data[elem]['hed'][0],2),
                  round(data[elem]['hed'][1],2),round(data[elem]['hed'][2],2)])
    csv_file.close()

print('done!')
```